# Need to add a "/" to end of url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

First I am new to this site and wanted to say thanks as I've already fixed 2 problems by following posted guides on here

Thanks!!

The only problem i cant seem to find an answer for is:

Due to seo recommendations I need to now add a "/" to the end of my sites url using .htaccess if pos on an apache server

I am using `.htaccess` to

1. redirect non www. url to www. url
2. remove .html from end of url

A copy of my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks for reading and for any help given!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#first add www to non-www adding backslash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#rewrite html extension (remove)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: probably something ive done but since copying above code website doesnt work Its added about 10 www. to the beginning and 10 / to the end?!? Have deleted .htaccess file sill doesnt work Have deleted and re uploaded site Still doesnt work?!?!?!?!?!?! Have deleted cookies for site on my laptop Still doesnt work?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: right restarted laptop and its all back to normal!!

Comment: so back to square one... non www. redirects to www. and .html has been removed from end of url Only thing still to do is add a / to the end of my url?!?

Comment: current .htaccess file     RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]